# Identify if a value is a Perfect Square and if so, then push it into an empty array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to identify if a value is a Perfect Square and if that's the case, I want to push it into an array. I know that there is a built-in function that allows for it but I want to create an algorithm that does it. :)

Input: num = 16
Output: [4]
Example 2:

Input: num = 25
Output: [5]
Example 2:

Input: num = 14
Output: []

```
var isPerfectSquare = function(value) {
  var perfectSquareVal = []
  var highestValue = value;
  var lowestValue = 0;
  while (lowestValue < highestValue) {
    var midpoint = 1 + Math.floor((highestValue + lowestValue)/2);
    if (midpoint * midpoint === value) {
      perfectSquareVal.push(midpoint);
    } else if (midpoint * midpoint > value) {
      highestValue = midpoint;
    } else if (midpoint * midpoint < value) {
      lowestValue = midpoint;
    }
  }
  console.log(perfectSquareVal);
};

isPerfectSquare(16);
```

Comment: and what exacly is the question? what do you need help with, as in. where does this code go wrong where you expected something else for example

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't just checking if the square root of the input is an integer? `const isPerfectSquare = num => Math.sqrt(num)%1 === 0;`

Answer (score 4):

That seems really complicated to check if a number is a square, you could simply check if the square root is an Integer:

```
var isPerfectSquare = function(value) {
    return Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(value));
}
```

And if the function returns true, then push to array.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would you do it assuming that there is no built-in function? I'm just doing this for practice. Thanks!

Comment: Can I use Math.sqrt or not even this one ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the algorithm a bit by

- taking the arthmetic mean with a flored value,
- return if the product is found (why an array for the result?),
- check only the greater oroduct because the smaller one is included in the check for equalness,
- use decremented/incremented values, becaus the actual value is wrong,
- keep a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), take ouput to the outside.

```js
var isPerfectSquare = function (value) {
    var highestValue = value,
        lowestValue = 0;

    while (lowestValue < highestValue) {
        let midpoint = Math.floor((highestValue + lowestValue) / 2),
            product = midpoint * midpoint;

        if (product === value) return midpoint;

        if (product > value) highestValue = midpoint - 1;
        else lowestValue = midpoint + 1;
    }
};

console.log(isPerfectSquare(25));
console.log(isPerfectSquare(250));
```